# FTPing a file to Mainframe using Java, Apache Common Net

Tags: java, file, networking, apache-commons, mainframe

I'm am trying to upload a file into mainframe server using FTP. My code is below

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();  
InputStream in = null;  
FileInputStream fis = null;  
try {  
    client.connect("10.10.23.23");  
    client.login("user1", "pass123");  
    client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);  
    int reply ;  
    reply = client.getReplyCode();  

    System.out.println("Reply Code:"+reply);  

    if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){            
        System.out.println("Positive reply");  
        String filename ="D:\\FILE.txt";  

        in = new FileInputStream(filename);  
        client.storeFile("FILE.TXT", in);  
        client.logout();  
        fis.close();        
    } else {  
        System.out.println("Negative reply");  
    }
} catch(final Throwable t){  
        t.printStackTrace();  
}
```

The code gets struck in `client.storeFile("FILE.TXT", in);`
I am unable to debug. Please suggest ways / solutions.

Comment: You're doing fis.close(); on not initialized object and it causes NPE on my machine.

Comment: You should probably also check the return value of storeFile, and close in.

Comment: What kind mainframe is it? Does it use EBCDIC? The docs say: "The only file types directly supported are FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE and FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE . Because there are at least 4 different EBCDIC encodings, we have opted not to provide direct support for EBCDIC. To transfer EBCDIC and other unsupported file types you must create your own filter InputStreams and OutputStreams and wrap them around the streams returned or required by the FTPClient methods." http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm not sure of Mainframe type, But the terminal type is IBM-3278-2. I further tried to upload the file using command prompt FTP utility. It just stops responding after SEND command.

Comment: Have you tried  `String [] fileNames = ftp.listNames();` just to see that you are indeed in some valid directory ? Also try to store it using the entire mainframe path ("root.somepath.someotherpath.file") (note lack of .txt) . For some mainframes you will need to add apostrophes : ("'root.somepath.someotherpath.file'"). Good luck!

Comment: Did you get this sorted ever? We don't have files called FILE or FILE.TXT, and you probably didn't know what "qualifiers" you needed, or whether it was going to a plain sequential file or to a PDS/PDSE. It would be good if you could update with what resolved it, so we don't keep getting "answers" for this...

Answer (score 1):

First there is what Lukas said fis is null, but I have a bunch of other questions.  What is FTPClient?  It is not sun.net.ftp.FtpClient as that class has no `store()` method.  Other things to consider is logging into the mainframe, where I work you can't just grab files off the mainframe without first logging in.  There can be more things to consider but lets start there.

Comment: FTPclient is the apache commons client: [link](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be changing to a specific directory before uploading the file. There are two ways of changing directories on the Mainframe. If you need to upload to a PDS you would execute a command like the following from with in the windows ftp client.

```
cd USERID.DATASET.PREFIX
```

If you need to upload a file to the USS subsystem you would execute a command like the following.

```
cd '/direone/dirtwo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that user1 has access permissions to ftp?  It is possible to grant those on a very granular level so that you can list files and submit jobs, but not put files.
The fact that it dies right after your SEND seems like that might be a good candidate.  I would call your RACF / ACF2 / Whatever-security-product person you have and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

1. first remove the file extension from the file name
2. enclose the resultant file name after trimming within single quotes
3. now put the above string as the first parameter of storeFile() method